# Clustering F/OSS Library for .NET

Tags: .net, cluster-analysis

Anyone aware of F/OSS library for clustering algorithms? Specifically interested in Hierarchical Clustering. Surely there are some libs available, not requiring writing up from scratch.

p.s I know about NMath, it is $ ware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to write my own. I will open-source it asap.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried NGrid?
http://www.ohloh.net/p/ngrid

And here's another "Legion"
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/gridcomputing.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a clustering library for algorithms such as k-means, c-means, hierarchical etc. (not grid computing)