# .Net open source grid computation library

Tags: c#, .net, grid, distributed-computing

I'm looking for an open source (FLOSS preferable) library for grid/distributed computing with C#/.Net.

I'm aware of [Alchemi.Net](http://www.cloudbus.org/~alchemi/) and [NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/), but I notice that neither have been updated in the last 4 or 5 years.

Is anyone aware of either a purely .Net framework, or a good .Net wrapper around a solid grid computing framework, preferably one that is well maintained and has an active community?

Comment: There's a question with a similar title, but it refers to data clustering (k-means, hierarchical etc.) rather than distributed computing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798662/clustering-f-oss-library-for-net

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at [Qizmt](http://code.google.com/p/qizmt/), but admittedly haven't had a chance to try it yet.  It follows the MapReduce model.

Answer (score 0):

You can look [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/) platform, it has [IceGrid](http://www.zeroc.com/icegrid/index.html) service and set of feature that you may found useful in a real world distributed computing.

Comment: FWIW though the platform is GPL, they still expect you to pay commercial licences for it. Even if you try to go the GPL route, you would be required to release your entire application under GPL. (because it's not LGPL like other library frameworks).